# Extend TFS Source-Control-Explorer

Tags: tfs, vsix, source-control-explorer

I already created a Visual Studio 2012 extension to place a ComboBox at Source Control Explorer.

I am using this guid at my vsct file:

```
  <!-- MyComboBox in Source Control Explorer -->
  <Combo guid="myMainguid" id="cmdSSEComboBox" priority="0x0700" type="DropDownCombo" defaultWidth="130" idCommandList="cmdSSEGetItemsComboBox">
    <Parent guid="guidSourceControlExplorer" id="SSEToolBar" />
    <CommandFlag>IconAndText</CommandFlag>
    <CommandFlag>CommandWellOnly</CommandFlag>
    <Strings>
      <ButtonText>MyComboBox:</ButtonText>
    </Strings>
  </Combo>

<!-- Source Control Explorer -->
<GuidSymbol name="guidSourceControlExplorer" value="{FFE1131C-8EA1-4D05-9728-34AD4611BDA9}">
  <IDSymbol name="SSEToolBar" value="0x1106"/>
</GuidSymbol>
```

I want to place "**MyComboBox**" in the group below, the same group where there is the label "Source location" with the navigator.

Is it possible?
Thanks,
William Sade

Answer (score 1):

It is very unlikely that the Source Control Explorer is a customizable element. Technically, it is not part of Visual Studio but an add-in/extension itself. Even if it is customizable, it most probably won't accept vsct stuff.

People have had to create their own [Source Control Explorer clones](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c6642e7f-1a58-4ff0-aef9-0322dcc2b28d) to customize stuff.

At best, you may be able to add your own custom toolbar via vsct to the Source Control Explorer window, which is a VS ToolWindow anyways. However, you will need the GUID for the toolbar. It is not listed in the [standard VS window guids](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/cc807687(v=VS.140,d=hv.2).aspx).

Hope this gives you at least a direction to look in.

EDIT:
You can explore the Source Control Explorer window using the code below. Essentially, enumerate all windows in DTE (in a VsPackage) and place a debug point when your window is found. Then you can explore it. In the screenshot you can see I drilled down to the CommandBar. You may be able to inject your combo there at runtime if not via VSCT.

[image: Finding the CommandBar]

```
 for (int i = 0; i < dte.Windows.Count; i++)
 {
     try
     {
         if (dte.Windows.Item(i).Caption.ToLower().Contains("source control"))
         {
             MessageBox.Show("");
         }
     }
     catch (Exception)
     {
     }
 }
```

Comment: Found one more bit of information: All ToolWindows can be found in this registry key: `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0_Config\ToolWindows`